# how can i get model object in exceptionFilter Asp.NetCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

I am working with a WEB application in ASP .NET Core 2.0 where I have a custom ExceptionAttribute filter that inherits from ExceptionFilterAttribute.

How can I access the Model object passed to a  action in POST call.

The mentioned method is passed a ExceptionContext but I could not find an easy and reliable way to get Model object from it and pass to ViewResult.

The filter I have, looks like the following:

```
public class ApiCallExceptionAttribute: ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;

    public ApiCallExceptionAttribute(
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //how can i accesss model object here and pass to ViewResult
        result.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(_modelMetadataProvider,context.ModelState);

        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

and the controller looks like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiCallExceptionAttribute))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Activation(ActivationViewModel model)
{
            //throw exception in controller content
}
```

Comment: any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any easy way to do that.

The approach I would take is to implement `IActionFilter` also on your class.

Read the model's info in `onActionExecuting()` and store it in `HTTPContext.Items`.

Then read it from `HttpContext.Items` when there is an exception.

**Resist the urge to store this information as a private field in your class because MVC do not create a new instance of it's filters for every request!**

```
 public class LogExceptionFilterAttribute : Attribute, IExceptionFilter, IActionFilter
    {

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Items["ActionArguments"] = context.ActionArguments;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }

        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var model = context.HttpContext.Items["ActionArguments"];
        }
    }
```